# PHP returning object echoing out the values

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working with codeigniter ona PHP project at the moment, and one the libraries I am using returns an object of database results, that looks like this,

```
    stdClass Object
(
    [user_id] => 2
    [firstname] => John
    [surname] => Doe
    [email] => jonh.doe@emailaddress.info
    [password] => 9d210a03bed920971fefab01b8f84a27
    [postcode] => W1 5ST
    [date_registered] => 2021-04-11 10:56:47
    [last_logged_in] => 2011-05-04 11:56:03
    [user_type_id] => 2
)
```

I am then trying to echo the values using the follow code, I sending user to my view by doing the following,

```
$data['users'] = $this->users_model->get_by($this->session->userdata('user_id');
$this->load->view('view', $data);
```

Then in my view I am doing the following,

```
echo $users->firstname;
```

However I get the following error at the top of my page,

> > A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: 4096
>
> Message: Object of class stdClass
>   could not be converted to string
>
> Filename: libraries/Parser.php
>
> Line Number: 63

How can I resolve this? Without changing how the database results are returned ideally.

Comment: "$data['users']" and "echo $user->firstname;" doesn't match. Just a misspell or is it the problem?

Comment: You're assigning to `users` yet accessing `user`. Is that a typo?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot echo an object directly. create a method [__toString](http://no.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring)() or [serialize](http://no.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php) the object before echoing.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track.  A few things.

You're missing a closing ) in this line.

```
$data['users'] = $this->users_model->get_by($this->session->userdata('user_id'));
```

Also, It's hard to know what is being returned by your users model.  Can you provide the code for $this->users_model->get_by()?  That's where your problem will be.

Make sure you have your db query returning the object as you expect.  You may need to add ->row() .

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's because you're sending a variable called "users" to your view.. but in your view you call the variable $user and not $users

if not... the [doc on views](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html) says:

> Note: If you use an object, the class
>   variables will be turned into array
>   elements.

Good Luck!

Comment: yah doc says that, but what does it really mean ? how to access those variables ?

Answer (score 0):

For Codeigniter, you need to call $users->result(), $users->result_array(), $users->row() or $users->row_array() to access the DB result object data

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

Assuming a single row is returned:

```
$data['users'] = $this->users_model->get_by($this->session->userdata('user_id');
$data['users'] = $data['users']->row();
$this->load->view('view', $data);
```